# Get message published before subscriber start

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a publisher node set to publish only once a message right after it started.
I have a subscriber node that subscribes to this topic but that is sometimes started a little time after the publisher (so its message is published before the subscriber has started)

How can the subscriber retrieve this message published before it started ?

I feel this may be done with QoS policies.
I created the subscription with a QoS History depth of 10 (according to the [documentation](https://docs.ros2.org/beta3/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1node_1_1Node.html#a5c3fe8426e737ff408fd28dea74e54a7)), but this message is not retrieved (but QoS policies are at least compatible since if a republish regularly the message after the subscriber started I receive it):

```
m_subMap = this->create_subscription<nav_msgs::msg::OccupancyGrid>("/map", 10, std::bind(&MapDataCallback, this, _1));
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383731/get-message-published-before-subscriber-start/) by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're right to look into QoS, but I think the setting you will want to look at is [`transient local`](https://answers.ros.org/question/379964/publishget-last-message-when-a-new-subscriber-subscribes-to-a-topic/#379981) (aka [latching](https://answers.ros.org/question/305795/ros2-latching/))

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on 2021-08-04**:
"latching" was indeed what I was looking for, thanks.
This code works, by setting bith the subscriber and the publisher to durability "transient local" (in a way insopired from the slam_toolbox code):

```
/* Publiher side */
m_mapPublisher = this->create_publisher<nav_msgs::msg::OccupancyGrid>(
"/map", rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::KeepLast(1)).transient_local().reliable());

/* Subscriber side */
rclcpp::QoS qosLatching = rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::KeepLast(1));
qosLatching.transient_local();
qosLatching.reliable();
m_subMap = this->create_subscription<nav_msgs::msg::OccupancyGrid>("/map", qosLatching, std::bind(&MapDataCallback, this, _1));
```